# Read CSV file from Connect In-DB tool in Alteryx

Tags: database, csv, alteryx

Hi all I have an Alteryx workflow that is designed to read data from Amazon Redshift with a **Connect In-DB** tool. I've been provided CSV files but I don't have access to Redshift, I want to run the workflow but I can't figure out how to import a CSV into the Connect In-DB tool. Any ideas how to do this?

[Alteryx Connect In-DB tool flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miiyd.png)

Comment: For "In-DB" it is assumed you're connecting to some sort of database. With a .csv, just import the flat file directly, using the regular Input Tool.

Comment: Is the goal to join the CSV data to the Redshift data or is the CSV data a copy of the Redshift data that you've been given as a substitute for proper access?

Answer (score 0):

As @johnjps111 mentioned in the comment, you need to replace all the in-database tools with an Input Tool that reads the .csv.  This assumes that the .csv was filtered and summarized to form the same output that would be coming from the in database tools.   Otherwise you would need to replicate them with their normal counterparts.